# BIND DNS Linux - forwarding queries to another DNS

Tags: bind

i have a server with dns setting pointing to a DNS linux (.157), i need to join this server to AD domain hosted by Microsoft AD. 
i need to forward SRV queries for ldap, from DNS linux to another DNS (Microsoft DNS, .149). the AD domain is corp.dom;
Having this configuration on my DNS linux:

```
  options {
    #listen-on port 53 { 172.23.133.157; 127.0.0.1; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { none; };
    allow-query { any; };
    allow-recursion { any; };
    directory       "/var/named";
    dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
    recursion yes;
    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;
    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

    version "REFUSED";
};

zone "corp.dom" {
      type forward;
      forward only;
      forwarders {172.23.133.149; };  //this is the Microsoft DNS where corp.dom resides
 };
```

i captured this output:

```
 [root@predns named]# dig srv _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.corp.dom

 ; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-18.el7_1.1 <<>> srv _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.corp.dom
 ;; global options: +cmd
 ;; Got answer:
 ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17251
 ;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 1
 ;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

 ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
 ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
 ;; QUESTION SECTION:
 ;_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.corp.dom. IN      SRV

 ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
 .                       518400  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
 .                       518400  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
 .                       518400  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
 .                       518400  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
 .                       518400  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
 .                       518400  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
 .                       518400  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
 .                       518400  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
 .                       518400  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
 .                       518400  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
 .                       518400  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
 .                       518400  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
 .                       518400  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.

 ;; Query time: 0 msec
 ;; SERVER: 172.23.133.157#53(172.23.133.157)
 ;; WHEN: mar giu 19 16:55:52 CEST 2018
 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 269
```

any help would be great!

---

full configuration of DNS linux:
I omitted type master zones because they work and they are not related to corp.dom:

```
acl "ihd" { 127.0.0.1/32; 172.23.133.128/28; 172.23.133.144/28; };
include "/etc/rndc.key";
controls {
     inet 127.0.0.1 allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
};

options {
    #listen-on port 53 { 172.23.133.157; 127.0.0.1; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { none; };
    forwarders { 172.23.133.149; };
    allow-query { any; };
    directory       "/var/named";
    dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
    recursion yes;
    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;
    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
    empty-zones-enable no;
    version "REFUSED";
};

view "internal" {
 match-clients { ihd; };
 allow-query { ihd; };
 # allow-recursion { ihd; };
 recursion no;


 zone "." IN {
      type hint;
      file "named.ca";
 };

 include "/etc/named.root.key";
 include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";

 zone "133.23.172.in-addr.arpa" IN {
      type master;
      file "172.23.133.zone";
      allow-transfer { 172.23.133.157; };
 };
 zone "corp.dom" {
      type forward;
      forward only;
      forwarders {172.23.133.149; };
      /*file "corp.dom.zone";
      allow-transfer { 172.23.133.157; };*/
 };

 view "external" {
 match-clients { any; };
 allow-query { any; };
 recursion no;

 zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
 };

 include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";


 };
```

Comment: Have you tried to set option `empty-zones-enable no;` as mentioned in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/535627/327632)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set `recursion no;` for the queries which match internal "ihd" acl.
All DNS forward queries are recursive queries, you need to set it to `recursion yes;` at least for "internal" view.

DNSSEC can also break communication for recursive queries. To make sure if DNSSEC isn't causing issue run dig with +cd and +dnssec options

```
dig srv _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.corp.dom @linux_dns_server_ip +cd
dig srv _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.corp.dom @linux_dns_server_ip +dnssec
```

If you get answer with +cd option and not with +dnssec, then you need to disable DNSSEC validation `dnssec-validation no;`

Comment: please, have a look at my next reply to this topic, thanks for help

Comment: This is actually reply to next comment, not sure why it appeared here. You need to set recursion yes; for "internal" view.

Comment: your suggestion helped me, now i can see for the first time queries forwarded to Microsoft, thanks. But i have still problem. I'm going to ahead

Comment: you are the boss ;)

Answer (score 0):

Configuration is OK, but is your Bind DNS server(Linux) able to communicate with Microsoft AD DNS server?
You can test it by running dig command on Linux DNS server.

```
dig srv _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.corp.dom @ip_of_AD_DNS
```

If output is correct, then only check for configuration on Linux DNS server.

Comment: it works, so DNS Microsoft works...i'm going to post the full configuration of my DNS LINUX for further help